# how to determine whether a thread finish its work or not

Tags: linux, multithreading

Here I have a task,and I divided the task into many subtasks,then I create many threads and each handle a subtask. My problem is that, if one(or some) of these threads occur some error and quit without finish it subtask, so how can I do to find out which threads occur error and fix the failure.
May be I can use log to record the status of each threads?
or I can just use some thread handle technique like pthread_join()?

Comment: join just inform you the end-of-life, so it would be success, or fail. each thread might specify a flag which indicates its successful status before it goes dead, success or fail.

Comment: You could also have each thread write its status to an atomic variable.

Comment: C++11 has support for future return values. Look into std::async and std::future. The return value can be a status enumerate, indicating whether the thread completed successfully. You can fire off a bunch of asyncs, then evaluate all of the future values.

Comment: ok,i will try the future values.Thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with *work*?  `pthread_join()` is a good semantics for considering a thread done, as it cannot do anything after it has finished execution.  But signalling another way is some way of telling that I have finished something but not all (I can do more after this signalling).